# Statement decorators

Tags: python, function, decorator

We have some code that looks like this:

```
from third_party_library import foo

for n in range(3):
    try:
        foo(args)
        break
    except:
        print "Retry %i / 3" % n
```

I would like to use a decorator, allowing our code to be more consise, looking like this:

```
from third_party_library import foo

@retry(3)
foo(args)
```

This gives a syntax error.  Am I missing something, or does python just not allow decorators on statements?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Decorators can only be applied to function and class *definitions* such as:

```
@decorator
def func():
    ...

@decorator
class MyClass(object):
    ...
```

You cannot use them anywhere else in the language.

---

To do what you want, you could make a normal `retry` function and pass `foo` and `args` as arguments.  The implementation would look something like this:

```
def retry(times, func, *args, **kwargs):
    for n in xrange(times):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            break
        except Exception:  # Try to catch something more specific
            print "Retry %i / %i" % (n, times)
```

Comment: The 3 should come first so that `*args` (and `**kwargs`) can be used to support functions with more than one argument. Otherwise exactly what I was going to suggest.

Comment: You can use function decorators inline. For example, if the OP did have a hypothetical decoratory `retry()`, they could call `retry(3)(foo)()` in their for loop.

Answer (score 5):

Python does not allow decorators on statements; they are only allowed on class & function definitions.  You can see this near the top of [the grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/grammar.html).

Answer (score 3):

It's true that decorators cannot be applied to statements, and you can do the retry function as described in the other answer. In my opinion however there is  a more Pythonesque approach, namely is the use of the context manager. Let me rephrase your problem in a runnable manner, and let the code speak:

```
import random
def foo():
    """The function you were importing, now runnable"""
    n = random.randint(1,10)
    print "Got", n,
    if n < 8:
        raise Exception("Failed")

for n in range(3):
    try:
        foo()
        break
    except:
        print "Retry %i / 3" % n
```

Using an (automatically generated) ContextManager, the code will look like:

```
import random
def foo():
    """The function you were importing, now runnable"""
    n = random.randint(1,10) 
    print "Got", n, 
    if n < 8:
        raise Exception("Failed")

from contextlib import contextmanager
@contextmanager
def retry():
    """Something similar to a decorator for statements"""
        try:
            yield
        except:
            print "Retry %i / 3" % n

for n in range(3):
    with retry():
        foo()
        break
```

As you can see, the solution is not perfect, since the ContextManager can execute the statement(s) exactly once (on at the time of the yield) and not in a loop. However, at least for this simple example, it seems more clear to me, even though the looping must be done outside. See https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/contextlib.html and https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers for details

Answer (score 2):

Decorators were introduced in Python 2.4. Initially, they were only supported for function and method declarations ([PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)).

Python 3 extended them to class declarations ([PEP 3129](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/)).

Decorators are not supported on any other language constructs.

Answer (score 2):

The decorator itself is the function that wraps the function ( take the argument as the function) and return the new function;

So you can use it inline like this:

```
retry(3)(foo)(args)
#retry(3) is function accept function
#retry(3)(foo) return the new function 
#then u exploit the function by call with the `args`
```