# workarounds for (pseudo-)decorating a for loop in python?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, decorator, python-decorators

Of course I know this is not directly possible as in Python, as read in

[Statement decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245450/statement-decorators)

but still I would like to find a way to programmatically turn (on and off) a loop as:

```
for i in range(L[:]):
    # do stuff
```

into

```
for i in range(L[0:N])):
    # estimate how much time it
    # took to run the loop over a subset N element of the list
for i in range(L):
    # do stuff on the full list
```

Is there any pythonic way to do so?

Comment: How would you like to "turn on and off" this feature? It seems to me the easiest thing would be to have `N` an optional parameter which defaults to `None`.

Comment: What is L? It seems to be integer in one of your examples and some iterable type in the other example. And When ``L[0:N]`` is a sequence, ``range(L[0:N])`` does not make sense.

Comment: Why don't you put the for loop in a function, which you can than use as a decorator? Does it need to be a decorator?

Comment: @allo corrected

Comment: it does need it to be a decorator but I was wondering if I modify alter all the for loops within a large script at once, to behave similarly to the answer of @Dschoni

Comment: I still doubt that your first line is working at all. Are you sure it should not be ``for i in L[:]``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume `L` is a list

```
import time

def timed_loop(L,subset,timeout):
    start = time.time()
    for i in L[0:subset]:
        do_something()
    stop = time.time()
    if stop-start < timeout:
        for i in L:
            do_something_else()
```

Comment: Nice. Would that work if L was a generic iterable as well?

Comment: as long as you can index L, I would say so.

Comment: to make it faster: don't redo L[0:subset] but go on with L[subset:]